# How to pass a JSON string as a POST param avoiding character encoding in Java?

Tags: java, json, post

I'm trying to send a POST param to a REST endpoint I have. This param is a JSON String, that contains special chars like double quotes ("). On the endpoint I keep on getting the String encoded.

THis is the request part:

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append(callBackURL);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("update", "{\"object\":\"page\",\"entry\":[{\"id\":\"316492991876763\",\"time\":1417436403,\"changes\":[{\"field\":\"feed\",\"value\":{\"item\":\"comment\",\"verb\":\"add\",\"comment_id\":\"321528008039928_323256911200371\",\"parent_id\":\"316492991876763_321528008039928\",\"sender_id\":100006737955082,\"created_time\":1417436403}}]}]}"));
    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(query.toString());
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
        System.out.println(e2.getMessage());
    }
```

Now in the endpoint part:

```
/**
 * Callback method that receives FB updates
 * @return 200 OK if everything goes OK, 401 ERROR otherwise
 */
@POST
@Path("/callback")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response facebookUpdate(String update, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    //parse it
    JsonElement json = jsonParser.parse(update);
    ...
}
```

What I'm getting is a String encoded like this:

```
%7B%22object%22%3A%22page%22%2C%22entry%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22316492991876763%22%2C%22time%22%3A1417436403%2C%22changes%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22feed%22%2C%22value%22%3A%7B%22item%22%3A%22comment%22%2C%22verb%22%3A%22add%22%2C%22comment_id%22%3A%22321528008039928_323256911200371%22%2C%22parent_id%22%3A%22316492991876763_321528008039928%22%2C%22sender_id%22%3A100006737955082%2C%22created_time%22%3A1417436403%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D
```

Something I cannot convert to a JsonElement...

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Thanks!
Alejandro

**UPDATE:**

I found what the problem was, so I'm explaining it here in case anyone has the same problem.

I was trying to pass a param using a BasicNameValuePair, like so:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("update", "{\"object\":\"page\",\"entry\":[{\"id\":\"316492991876763\",\"time\":1417436403,\"changes\":[{\"field\":\"feed\",\"value\":{\"item\":\"comment\",\"verb\":\"add\",\"comment_id\":\"321528008039928_323256911200371\",\"parent_id\":\"316492991876763_321528008039928\",\"sender_id\":100006737955082,\"created_time\":1417436403}}]}]}"));
```

I've changed to a simple StringEntity, like this:

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(query.toString());
```

Thus, I don't need to decode. Mistery remains on why passing an Array of BasicNameValuePair will encode the String...

Comment: Don't do that. Don't put JSON in a form parameter. If anything, use a multipart request and have one of them be `application/json`.

Comment: In any case, your server should be smart enough to decode the encoded form parameter back to its original characters. You can then use those with your JSON parser.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is not coming from a form, it is actually coming from Facebook, but I'm unit testing this and I'm trying to emulate the response from FB, and it comes as a JSON string

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Regarding the decoding...any pointers?

Comment: I'm surprised your container isn't doing the decoding for you. You can use `URLDecoder`.

Comment: When the response was coming from FB I neved needed to decode, so I'm wondering why if I do the request myself when testing, I need to...kinda weird...

Answer (score 0):

use annotation above the method you want to produce JSON from

```
@Produces("application/json")
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't want' to produce any JSON anywhere...I don't get your point